# building large shift registers

Tags: digital-logic

I want to build a 500 cell shift register using the TI SN74AUP1G79 flip flop.How much current must my power supply put out to drive this many flip flops and how much current must my clock buffer put out to drive all the clocks? I am running the register at 1.54mhz. Thank you.

Comment: Use a CPLD, like one of the Altera MAX II devices. You will find it much easier than connecting 500 flip-flops together.

Comment: @Leon Thank you for the reply, I have to use discrete flip-flops for this job, it's for a proprietary design.

Comment: It's a silly way to do it!

Comment: @Leon: If you knew what I was doing you would see why I can't use a CPLD. Can you help me with my original question? Thanks!

Comment: You must use that flip-flop? You couldn't even use something like a 8-bit shift register?

Comment: @Tim - I guess you have a good reason to use that particular IC, but unless you can explain it to us, we'll all find it an idiotic idea. Like W5VO says, can't you at least use an 8-bit shift register? This would reduce IC count from 500 to 63, which still is much. If you need the outputs of every FF individually you can't use Leon's CPLD; they don't have 500 I/Os.

Comment: An FPGA would solve that problem. The Xilinx XC6SLX150 has 576 I/Os.

Comment: @stevenvh: My conjecture would be that the goal is to have the 500 flip flops mounted in physically different places; one may be able to use a four-wire or five-wire daisy-chained cable in such a case, whereas using larger chips would require running individual wires from each chip to the things it controlled.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, it's best to assume the worst case switching pattern, and in this case it will be the easiest. I will define worst case as the input to the shift register changing every clock cycle.

I'll break the power consumption down into several categories. This datasheet isn't exactly crystal clear, so I'm open to any corrections. These are also designed for very small capacitances, so if you have a very large load or long wires, you may be "swamping" these numbers.

**Assumptions:**

- No current consuming load, like LEDs
- \$V_{DD}\$ is not given, so it will be kept as a variable, and the maximum value will be calculated.
- All traces are small enough to minimize capacitance

**Leakage/Quiescent Power**

Listed as 0.9uA at worst case, this power comes out to:

\$500\times0.9\mu A \times V_{DD}=450\mu A\times V_{DD}\$ (0.36mW to 1.49mW)

**Internal (no load) Switching Power**

You won't find a figure for this in the datasheet. Instead, they give you the value of something called \$C_{pd}\$, which is the equivalent of the load capacitance for a given switching event. Depending on your \$V_{DD}\$, you will have different values of effective \$C_{pd}\$. [Texas Instruments describes](http://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/150/p/15632/60166.aspx) \$C_{pd}\$ as:

> The equivalent capacitance used to
>   determine the no-load dynamic power
>   dissipation per logic function for
>   CMOS devices.

I find this to be somewhat ambiguous for a flip-flop since it isn't clear whether the Data input transitions count. I will assume that they do not. The values would increase by 50% if the D input should be included.

\$500\times C_{pd}\times V_{DD}{}^2\times f=500\times 3.0pF \times V_{DD}{}^2\times 1.52MHz\$ (1.46mW to 24.83mW)

**Output Load Switching Power**

The next item is how much power is used to make all the output pins switch. At the bare minimum, each output will be driving one D input to the next flip-flop stage. Also, any board capacitance or additional loads will contribute to this power figure. Try to account for as much capacitance as possible.

\$C_{load}=\sum{Capacitance}=C_{Pin.D}+C_{wire}+?\$

\$C_{load}=1.5pF+3.5pF=5.0pF\$ (For the sake of calculation)

Then the output switching power is fairly easy to compute. If you have any appreciable capacitive load, your output switching power can skyrocket.

\$500\times C_{load}\times V_{DD}{}^2 \times f=500 \times 5.0pF \times V_{DD}{}^2 \times 760kHz\$ (1.22mW to 20.69mW)

**Total Power**

Again, this depends on your load and power supply voltage. For a worst-case switching pattern, we can simply add the three power losses listed, and get the result. The minimum value uses a \$V_{DD}\$ of 0.8V, and the maximum value uses a \$V_{DD}\$ of 3.3V.

\$\sum{power}=P_{leak}+P_{internal}+P_{load}\$

For \$V_{DD}=3.3V:\mbox{ }P_{total}=47.01mW\mbox{;    }I_{avg}=14.24mA\$

For \$V_{DD}=0.8V:\mbox{ }P_{total}=3.04mW\mbox{;    }I_{avg}=3.8mA\$

**Clocking Considerations**

It is difficult to determine the peak clock current without knowing more variables, including the board layout and clock tree structure and clock buffer behavior and the power supply voltage. However, delivering a clock pulse simultaneously to 500 clock sinks will be difficult. To make it even harder, the gate you have chosen is fast, so that reduces your margin. After you build your device, test it at the coldest operational temperature with the highest power supply voltage allowed and see if the data makes it through ok.

The capacitance of all the clock pins is 750pF, but that doesn't account for any wiring load.

Comment: By my reading of the data sheet, the ΔIC figure is suggesting that if the input is 0.6 volts short of VDD the device current may rise by 40-50uA; if that figure applies for all voltages between 0.6 and 2.6 volts, this could be significant.  If one tries to drive 750pF with a source that can source/sink 20mA (pretty beefy), and VDD is 3.2 volts, then for about 75ns the input will be between 0.6 volts and 2.6 volts.  If you're driving at 1.5MHz, the input will be in the 0.6-2.6 zone about half the time, adding another 40*500uA half the time, or about 10mA net.

Comment: @supercat: Good call. Without more information, it would be difficult to speculate on a short-circuit power. Multiple buffers could break up the load too. The flip-side of that is that there shouldn't be any short circuit power for VDD < 1.2V

Comment: @W5VO: There is, however, another issue I should also have mentioned: if one uses such a slow rise time, one runs a risk that one latch might see the clock before the "preceding" latch in the chain has done so.  Buffers may be needed not only to minimize shoot-through currents, but also to ensure correct operation.

Comment: @supercat - right, I thought I mentioned that. (maybe not explicitly enough). At VDD=3.3V, I figure that the inputs need to be synchronized better than 5ns

Comment: @W5VO: You said delivering it simultaneously would be difficult, but didn't specify why.  There are two issues that come up: (1) electrical propagation, and (2) threshold uncertainty.  It's possible to construct latches in such a way as to eliminate the second problem by making them sample the input when the clock voltage is below one threshold, and copy the previously-sampled input to the output when the clock is above a higher threshold.  If the worst-case values of the thresholds don't overlap, a slow rise will be good, ensuring that no latch sees the clock enter high region...

Comment: @W5VO: ...before the latch it's feeding has seen the clock leave the "low" region.  With such a latch, if the clock originated at the downstream end of the cable, one might have to worry about an RC cable delay skewing fast clocks edges, but slow clock edges would be safe.  I don't think the OP's chosen latch works like that, though; the issue isn't just ensuring that all latches see the same voltage simultaneously, but ensuring that they'll all act upon it either simultaneously or in the correct order.

Comment: @W5VO: BTW, I wonder why master-slave flip flops aren't more common (sample on one clock polarity; copy to output on the other).  A master-slave flip flop is electrically simpler than an edge-triggered one, and in many cases could be a drop-in replacement that would improve timing margins.

Answer (score 3):

W5VO gave an excellent answer covering exactly what you asked.

However, because I'm obsessed with driving LEDs and usually plan to drive them with a large shift register, let's see where that goes:

Driving 500 LEDs fairly dimly at 2 mA, requires 1000 mA = 1 A of current from your power supply; at 3.0 V that's 3 W of power (3000 mW) -- the power required by all of your shift registers and clock drivers combined is insignificant compared to that.

Alas, the output voltage appears to be inadequate to turn on blue or white LEDs.
But many LED displays only use red and green LEDs, and it's perfectly adequate for that.
Alas, the maximum "recommended" output current at is only 4 mA (either sink or source) -- enough to get a red or green LED to turn on, but not enough to give full brightness.
Sometimes other kinds of chips can drive an LED brighter, but allow the output voltage to drift into the range where it is no longer guaranteed to be recognized as a "1" or "0".
At Vcc = 3 V, this chip has an input range of Vih_min of 2.0 V and Vil_max of 0.9 V, so it can properly recognize the output of another identical chip even when that other chip is fully loaded with 4 mA, since that other chip gives a "high" output Voh of at least 2.55 V, and a "low" output Vol of less than 0.45 V.

"The" clock signal in many systems, including yours, drives hundreds of devices.
While I suppose one could use one really strong buffer to drive all of them,
many designers limit their fanout to a much smaller number.
I generally limit my fanout to around 20 gate inputs connected to any gate output.
When everything is together on one compact PCB, we make a [clock tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/clock_tree) --
but it makes no sense to use 500 of that chip on a compact PCB rather than driving those 500 LEDs with 8 bit shift registers such as 74AHC595 or one of the other alternatives mentioned.

I'm assuming you are driving these LEDs in a very long, narrow strip,
each LED driven by its own flip-flop.
So for something like this I would buffer the clock signal every 19 flip-flops (or perhaps some more convenient number like 16 or 10 or 8),
so the main clock that drives the string drives only the first buffer
(which requires insignificant amounts of power),
and each buffer drives 19 or fewer flip-flops and the next buffer in the chain
(which also requires insignificant amounts of power per gate, but over the course of all 500 flip-flops and roughly 50 buffers, it adds up).

At 1.5 pF of input capacitance per gate that's 500*1.5 = 750 pF of gate capacitance for the flip-flops, and roughly 1/10 of that for the clock buffers. At guestimated (?) 4 pF of trace capacitance per gate we have 2,000 pF of trace capacitance.
The (dynamic) power drawn charging and discharging those capacitances is P = fCV^2, so at 1.54 MHz and 3.0 V we require (estimated) (1.54 MHz)(2825 pF)(3.0 V)^2 = 39 mW.
That's still insignificant compared to those LEDs.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out, you are building up good karma! :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that one 20mA LED at 3.3V will have more power consumption than the logic. I didn't see that LEDs were driven anywhere - but it's likely that the load will dominate power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

If trying to minimize the current used by a shift register implemented in a CPLD, and if all you need is an output delayed by some number of clocks, you can minimize the number of latch transitions by keeping a count of the number of shifts and storing and accessing them round-robin fashion.  Depending upon the CPLD family used, this may allow one to store two or three bits per macrocell (at the cost of a few macrocells of overhead).  If, for example, each macrocell could, when used in register mode, have a combinatorial feedback term as well as an I/O pin input, one could hold one bit in the combinatorial output (used as a transparent latch), one in the latch, and one on the I/O pin (using a pin-keeper circuit).

On the first cycle, sample the I/O pin from macrocell 3 (as the shift-register output), enable the driver on macrocell 2 (causing the registered value to be copied to the pin), and latch the input data into macrocell 1.  On the next cycle, sample macrocell 4, enable macrocell 3, and latch macrocell 2.  Then macrocell 5, 4, and 3, etc. wrapping when one reaches the end.  The result will be 3N-3 bits stored in N macrocells.  Note that some lower-pin-count CPLDs have internal pin drivers which are not brought out to the package; these can be used for holding data, but the only way I've found to program them is to claim to be using a larger-pin-count package.  I'm not sure whether the behavior of such non-bounded pins is guaranteed.  On the other hand, being able to store 3 bits per macrocell can be a lot nicer than storing one per.

Comment: Thank you but I can't use a CPLD, I have to use discrete flip-flops.

Comment: @Tim Smith: Any particular reason?  I would suggest that if you're using a lot of flip flops and want to minimize current consumption, you might do well to use a counter and one or more demultiplexers and multiplexers (or maybe a one-hot counter and discrete gates).  For example, by adding a 74HC4019 (one-hot decade counter), ten 'nand' gates, and a ten-input "nor" gate, one could probably cut the current consumption by a factor of eight or more.  Wire up ten strings of fifty flip flops, and use the outputs from the 74HC4019 to clock them.

Comment: @Tim Smith: Use the ten "nand" gates to combine the outputs of the shift registers with the appropriate 4019 outputs, and use the "nor" gate to combine them.  The result would be that on each clock cycle, the counter would advance once, 50 latches would see a rising clock edge, 50 would see a falling clock edge, two NANDs would see input changes, and some inputs on the NOR might change.  Power dissipation from that should be much less than that of clocking all 500 flip flops.

Comment: I don't want to add any other logic gates to the circuit; and I don't care about minimizing the current, I just need to know what my power requirements will be for driving all 500 flip-flops and their respective clocks. I looked at the data sheet for this TI flip flop but i didn't understand the ratings. For instance,the sheet gives a figure of .5uA for Iclock. Does this mean I just multiply this figure by 500 to figure my clock buffer output current? Also they dont tell you the imput impedence of the D imput, how can you calculate current draw from the previous stage?